# Access hosting environment before building WebHost

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

In my `Program.cs` Main method, I would like to read [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets#security-app-secrets), configure a logger and then build the `WebHost`.

```
public static Main(string[] args)
{

    string instrumentationKey = null; // read from UserSecrets

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsEvents(instrumentationKey)
        .CreateLogger();

    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}
```

I *can* get to the configuration by building my own, but I quickly end up in a mess trying to access hosting environment properties:

```
public static Main(string[] args)
{
    var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production";
    var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    // Add user secrets if env.IsDevelopment().
    // Normally this convenience IsDevelopment method would be available 
    // from HostingEnvironmentExtensions I'm using a private method here.
    if (IsDevelopment(envName))
    {
        string assemblyName = "<I would like the hosting environment here too>"; // e.g env.ApplicationName
        var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(assemblyName));
        if (appAssembly != null)
        {
            configBuilder.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true); // finally, user secrets \o/
        }
    }
    var config = configBuilder.Build();
    string instrumentationKey = config["MySecretFromUserSecretsIfDevEnv"];

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsEvents(instrumentationKey) // that.. escallated quickly
        .CreateLogger();

    // webHostBuilder.UseConfiguration(config) later on..
    BuildWebHost(args, config).Run();
}
```

Is there an easier way to access `IHostingEnvironment` before building the `WebHost`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `main` method, you cannot get the `IHostingEnvironment` instance before building the WebHost, as hosting is not yet created. And you cannot create a new valid instance properly, as [it must be initialized using WebHostOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingEnvironmentExtensions.cs).

---

For application name you may use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Name`

---

For environment name use what you currently do (I assume something like this is used in your IsDevelopment() method):

```
var environmentName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
bool isDevelopment = string.Equals(
           "Development",
            environmentName,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

See, methods like `IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` are [extension methods that simply do string comparison internally](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingEnvironmentExtensions.cs):

```
    public static bool IsDevelopment(this IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        if (hostingEnvironment == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hostingEnvironment));
        }

        return hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development);
    }


    public static bool IsEnvironment(
        this IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        string environmentName)
    {
        if (hostingEnvironment == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hostingEnvironment));
        }

        return string.Equals(
            hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName,
            environmentName,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
```

---

Note regarding `AddJsonFile`: as file name is sensitive in Unix OS, sometimes it's better to use `$"appsettings.{envName.ToLower()}.json"`  instead of.

Comment: Thanks @Set. I have used a version of this to get the bootstraping working with user secrets, but I was just wondering if there was another way of rearraging the process that's easier. The new way of configuring the host is so nice that I felt it was a shame to tear it down and have my own methods doing the same things the hosting extension methods do. Thanks for the tip on `envName.ToLower()`.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do something similar. I wanted to set Kestrel listen options based on the environment. I just save the IHostingEnvironment to a local variable while I am configuring the apps configuration. Then later on I use that variable to make a decision based on the environment. You should be able to follow this pattern to accomplish your goal.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        IHostingEnvironment env = null;

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .UseStartup<Startup>()
              .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
              {
                  env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                  config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                  if (env.IsDevelopment())
                  {
                      var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
                      if (appAssembly != null)
                      {
                          config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
                      }
                  }

                  config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                  if (args != null)
                  {
                      config.AddCommandLine(args);
                  }
              })
              .UseKestrel(options =>
              {
                  if (env.IsDevelopment())
                  {
                      options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 44321, listenOptions =>
                      {
                          listenOptions.UseHttps("testcert.pfx", "ordinary");
                      });
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
                  }
              })
              .Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @GlennSills. I think this is a handy way of going about it, but for my case, I needed the hosting environment _before_ building the webhost.

Comment: Perfect for me as I only needed it during `ConfigureKestrel` step

Answer (score 1):

In .Net Core 2.0 you can do like this

```
var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
var environment = webHostBuilder.GetSetting("environment");
```